# Example of a curvature with no associated metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, tensor

Is there a concrete example of a $4$ tensor $R_{ijkl}$ with the same symmetries as the Riemannian curvature tensor, i.e.
\begin{gather*}
R_{ijkl} = - R_{ijlk},\quad R_{ijkl} = R_{jikl},\quad R_{ijkl} = R_{klij}, \\
R_{ijkl} + R_{iklj} + R_{iljk} = 0.
\end{gather*}
for which there is no metric for which it is the Riemannian curvature tensor?

The existence of such a curvature was already shown by [Robert Bryant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202211/equations-satisfied-by-the-riemann-curvature-tensor), however, I'm looking for a concrete example.

Comment: Do you want a local example or is a global example enough?  A trivial global example would be the zero tensor on a sphere $S^n$ for $n\geq 2$ (or any other manifold that can't admit a flat metric).

Comment: Choose a tensor field that does not meet the differential Bianchi identity.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin, is that enough? I know it has to hold at a point if the coordinates are such that the Christoffel symbols vanish. But otherwise it does not have to hold. But I guess you can say that there do not exist any coordinates for which the Boanchi identity holds at the given point.

Comment: @DeaneYang yes, you are right --- we do not have connection.

Comment: I don't know any systematic way to find an explicit example, but @AntonPetrunin

Comment: @DeaneYang Do you know what happens when you take the Berger spheres and shrink the fiber direction to zero?  In the limit you get a torsion free connection and Riemann curvature like tensor, but naively it is not associated to a Riemannian metric anymore (as the natural candidate is not positive definite any longer).  Unfortunately, I don't have a good explanation for why there isn't some other more exotic metric that does have this tensor field as its curvature.

Comment: @RBega2, nice observation and question. Offhand, I don't know.

Comment: @RBega2 The curvature tensor will be the same as in $\mathbb{S}^2_{1/2}\times\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple example (which just uses Deane Yang/Robert Bryant's idea) is to consider any space of dimension at least three and consider the tensor field
$$ R_{ijkl} = f(x)(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}-\delta_{il}\delta_{jk})$$
where $f(x)$ is your favorite function which changes sign and whose derivative is non-vanishing when $f=0$ (thanks to Robert Bryant for the correction). When $f=0$, this curvature tensor has constant sectional curvature $0$, no matter what metric we choose.

However, we can now apply the proof of [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma_(Riemannian_geometry)) (i.e., trace the second Bianchi identity twice) to see that when $f$ vanishes, we have that
$$dR=\frac{n}{2}dR$$
where $R$ is the scalar curvature.
As such, the differential of the scalar curvature must vanish when $f=0$. However, no matter which metric we pick, there is no way to make this happen if the differential of $f$ is nonzero as it goes from being positive to negative.

Edit: My original answer had a mistake which was pointed out in the comments. Here is a revised version which uses the same idea which should (hopefully) work.

Comment: Nice and simple.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work.  There are non constant functions $h(x)$ such that $g = h(x)\,\bigl (\mathrm{d}x^1)^2 + \cdots +  (\mathrm{d}x^n)^2\bigr)$ has constant sectional curvature.  For example, $h(x) = 4/(1+|x|^2)^2$.  Won't the Riemann curvature tensor of $g$ have the above form for a nonconstant $f(x)$?

Comment: Moreover, in dimension $3$, if $f(x)$ is nonvanishing, then $R_{ijkl}=f(x)(\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}-\delta_{il}\delta_{jk})$ *is* locally the Riemann curvature tensor of some metric $g$.  I proved this when $f$ is real-analytic (and nonvanishing) and later DeTurck and Yang proved this when $f$ is smooth (and nonvanishing).

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the correction. I guess to fix this we can add the assumption that f changes sign, right? That will definitely contradict Schur’s lemma then.

Answer (score 6):

@AntonPetrunin's comment points to, I think, another way to describe the counterexample given by Robert Bryant in his answer.

Consider a curvature-like tensor
$$
R_{ijkl}(dy^i\wedge dy^j)(dy^k\wedge dy^l)
$$
where $(y^1, \dots, y^n)$ are coordinates in a neighborhood of $0$. If $R$ is the curvature tensor of a Riemanian metric, then there exists a change of coordinates $y=\phi(x)$, such that $\phi(0) = 0$, $\partial_i\phi^j(0) = \delta_i^j$, and, with respect to the coordinates $x= (x^1, \dots, x^n)$, the Christoffel symbols vanish at $0$. It follows by the second Bianchi identity that at the point $0$,
$$
\partial_mR_{ijkl}-\partial_lR_{ijkm} = 0.
$$

Now consider a curvature-like tensor $R$ in a neighborhood of $0$ such that $R(0) = 0$ but for some choice of $i,j,k,l,m$,
$$
\partial_mR_{ijkl} - \partial_lR_{ijkm} \ne 0.
$$
You can now verify that this inequality will still hold at $0$ for any change of coordinates. Therefore, this tensor cannot be the curvature tensor of a Riemannian metric.

Comment: Your example is basically what I gave in my answer that  the OP linked.  It may be that the OP will not consider your class of examples sufficiently 'explicit' either.

Comment: @RobertBryant, sorry about that. I'm editing the answer to attribute this to you properly.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't worried about 'attribution'.  I was just pointing out that it's not as 'concrete' as the OP might want.  What I was thinking was that the OP might just want a 'concrete' answer, such as $R = x^3\,(\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\mathrm{d}x^2)\otimes (\mathrm{d}x^1\wedge\mathrm{d}x^2)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$.